# Exception Value: string indices must be integers : Render bundle error vue + django

Tags: html, django, vue.js, webpack

im using webpack loader to inyect my vue app into django, here is the code:

Settings :

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
'DEFAULT':{
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME':'/',
    'STATS_FILE':os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'aptim-frontend/dist','webpack-stats.json')

}}
```

vue config file :

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker"); 
module.exports = {
  // on Windows you might want to set publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
  publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: "./dist/",

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

config
  .plugin("BundleTracker")
  .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: "../frontend/webpack-stats.json" }]);

config.resolve.alias.set("__STATIC__", "static");

config.devServer
  .public("http://0.0.0.0:8080")
  .host("0.0.0.0")
  .port(8080)
  .hotOnly(true)
  .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
  .https(false)
  .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });},};
```

And the html line where I get the error is at the index html

```
 {% render_bundle 'app' %}
```

ERROR :Exception Value: string indices must be integers

Comment: The official github issue for this is here: https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/issues/227

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue in the great Udemy course [The Complete Guide to Django REST Framework and Vue JS](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-django-rest-framework-and-vue-js/learn/lecture/14288448#questions/9986952/). You probably cannot read the answer from Michele Saba if you are not subscribed.

It probably has something to do with the package versions and them being alpha. Downgrading to

- webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
- django-webpack-loader==0.7.0

worked for me. Downgrade using:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
```

Comment: It worked to solve the problem with `Django 3.1.5` and `django-webpack-loader 0.7.0`

Comment: It worked to solve the problem with Django 3.2.7

Answer (score 4):

Downgrade Webpack-bundle-tracker as told by @Frans

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
```

In `vue.config.js`

```
config
    .plugin('BundleTracker')
    .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: './webpack-stats.json'}])
```

Then delete the `dist` folder with the old `webpack-stats.json`

In this version and with this config `webpack-stats.json` file is generated in `frontend` not in `frontend/dist`
So you must change `STATS_FILE` in `settings.py` 
(for example if your Vue project is `frontend`)

```
'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend','webpack-stats.json'),
```

Then restart Vue and Django web-servers.

Answer (score 2):

Exception Value: string indices must be integers

i got this strange error too, confirmed downgrade to webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3 works.